# DNS over SOCKS proxy with Perl

Tags: perl, proxy, dns, socks, resolve

I'm trying to write a script that sends requests over a SOCKS5 proxy.
Something I wanted to do was to proxy the DNS requests over SOCKS. I manage to do this using the IO::Socket::Socks module.

This code allows me to connect to the SOCKS proxy and then resolve a hostname over SOCKS and connect to it after that.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::Socks;

my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new("127.0.0.1:9050") or die $@;
$sock = IO::Socket::Socks->start_SOCKS($sock, ConnectAddr => "example.com", ConnectPort => 80) or die $SOCKS_ERROR;

$sock->syswrite ("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n");
$sock->close();
```

This works fine. However I would like to show the user the IP resolved and I'm struggling to achieve this because for the `$sock` object, it seems to see the peer as the SOCKS proxy host rather than the real final host.

Does anyone know how can I retrieve the IP resolved from this DNS performed over SOCKS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> This code allows me to connect to the SOCKS proxy and then resolve a hostname over SOCKS and connect to it after that.

Not really. It connects to the SOCKS proxy and then connects to a given host by name. It does not resolve the hostname over SOCKS. Instead the resolving is done inside the SOCKS server only in order to connect to the given host and not done "over  SOCKS". In fact, the SOCKS server might even have an upstream SOCKS server where it just forwards the connect to without resolving the hostname by itself.

Also, there is no back channel to let the SOCKS client know what the SOCKS server did resolve. This is not needed since this kind of connection detail is not needed for the task as proxy.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So what you're saying is that it's a 2 step connection, is that right? The client connects to the SOCKS proxy and says "please connect to this host and this port" which the SOCKS proxy takes care of but never really tells the client any information about that second connection.
Given this, it won't be possible to retrieve the IP resolved, is that what you are saying? Thanks